# Compound words with "dog" in front

Tags: word-request, compounds

I need to make two compound words with the word "dog" to be the first part of the compound word. Those words should mean;
  1. person given all the hard, boring job;
  2. exhausted, worn out.
 I would appreciate it if someone can answer me... Thanks;

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can be answered by looking up words that start with "dog" in a physical dictionary.

Comment: @Jasper - Or an [online dictionary](https://onelook.com/?w=dog*&scwo=1&sswo=1&ssbp=1), even. I'd be willing to reopen this, but I'd want to see the OP explain their motive for asking the question. It seems like a "gimme the answer" homework help request to me.

Answer (score 1):

There is [**dogsbody**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dogsbody):

> [Lexico (Oxford)]
>   A person who is given menial tasks to do, especially a junior in an office.
>   *‘I got myself a job as typist and general dogsbody on a small magazine’*

Note that this seems to be an informally used UK expression. (Also, it's not normally hyphenated.)

--

And also [**dog-tired**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dog-tired):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : very tired : EXHAUSTED
>   // I was *dog-tired* and ready for bed.

Comment: Your second suggestion made me wonder if a hyphenated adjective counts as a compound word. [I guess it does](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/open-and-closed-compound-words/).